# best way to loop through entries in PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm preparing migration script in order to modify some objects from table. It can be that I will have to modify more than one thing on single object. Therefore returned results look like:

```
obj1 val1,
obj1 val2,
obj2 valX,
obj3 valY,
...
objN valN
```

In order to modify object I need to make a loop that will open a session in external system and modify object. 
I would like to spare some time/memory and open one order for obj1 and add both val 1 and val2 in within one session.

One of the ideas I had was to prepare some "staging" temp table where I would add entries in following format

```
obj1 val1 val2;
obj2 valX;
obj3 valY;
...
objN valN ...
```

But due to external system access rights on the Oracle DB I might not  be able to do that.
Therefore I was thinking if I would be able to aggregate values to enter within a loop avoiding generation of temporary tables.

May I kindly ask for suggestions in order to solve it "the nice" way?

Comment: `obj1 val1,
obj1 val2,...` is a string or it is records of the table in your system?

Comment: those are records from table

Comment: Then why don't you try `LISTAGG` with grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LISTAGG` concatenates the values of the same group while grouping.

Something like this will help you out:

```
SELECT OBJ_COL_NAME,
       LISTAGG(VAL_COL_NAME, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY VAL_COL_NAME) || ';' AS VALS
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY OBJ_COL_NAME;
```

for more details on `LISTAGG`, please refer to this [document](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php)

Cheers!!